# Add daterange filter to datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am trying to add a filter that filters dates in my table. The format on the date column is like this
"2020-12-07 11:56:51" . I have managed to implement some JavaScript on my data table, but it only filters on a range of numbers and not dates. Can anyone correct me into writing the write code to filter between 2 dates. This is the JavaScript code i have so far

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
    var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
    var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
        ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
        ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
        ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );

} );
```